# env.var value defined in tests are not available to global teardown in playwright

Tags: environment-variables, playwright

How to access an env variable in global teardown which is defined inside a tests ? the value is defined properly in the test as confirmed through logs but the same process.env variable when accessed inside teardown showing undefined.

tried to make it `global.process.env = process.env;` but still it gives undefined.

```
test.describe('tests', () => {
test('create a user', async ({ page, userAction }) => {
   process.env.id = await userAction.createUser();
    console.log(`create user with ${process.env.id}`);
```

this process.env.id  is defined inside a test (spec.ts) now when i try to access the same value in a global.teardown.ts i am getting undefined.

```
teardown('Delete user after the test', async ({ userAction }) => {
const userId = process.env.id || '';
console.log(`teardown the user ${userId}`);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code with your post so we can run it and debug the issues? Its hard to give you answers with no code to diagnose

Comment: Can you try to simply console.log the env var directly within the global teardown test please? I.e. dont declare a new local var and assign it. So delete out `const userId = process.env.id || '';` and just `console.log(process.env.id)`. See if that helps

Comment: yes tried this console.log(`teardown the user with11 ${process.env.id}`);

this still gives undefined .

Comment: Was the "11" a typo in your reply or is that the id?

Comment: that's a typo sorry , tried this as well console.log(process.env.id); it gives same undefined

Comment: Save this user-id to a file, and load this data from it